# Unable to run "composer install" mongosoft/yii2-soap-server in yii2

Tags: php, installation, yii2, composer-php, soapserver

I am trying to install a new widget but I am getting error. I need help with getting a solution.

[image]

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">= 5.6.28",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-twig": "^2.0",
        "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "~2.0",
        "nterms/yii2-pagesize-widget": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "^2.1",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
        "michelf/php-smartypants": "dev-lib",
        "kartik-v/yii2-markdown": "1.3.0",
        "cinghie/yii2-articles": "*",
        "xj/yii2-uploadify-widget": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
        "zxbodya/yii2-gallery-manager": "*@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-checkbox-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "@dev",
        "nickcv/yii2-encrypter": "*",
        "mongosoft/yii2-soap-server": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
        "limion/yii2-jquery-fileupload-widget": "~1.0",
        "wadeshuler/yii2-ckeditor-cdn": "~1.0",
        "life2016/yii2-tagsinput": "*",
        "sunhater/kcfinder": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

I have already looked into some solutions but none of them have worked. I am stuck at this from hours and I am getting nothing in result. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: php soap is install in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your php is installed without [SOAP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) which is required by `mongosoft/yii2-soap-server`.

The best way to deal with it is to add the extension to your installation but the way how to do it depends on how you've installed the php itself.

If you've compilled the php from source code you should recompile it while adding  `--enable-soap` switch to the `configure` command.

If you've installed php from system's package repository try looking for a package with name like `php-soap`, `php7.4-soap` or something similar.

If someone else is managing the server for you, try contacting them and ask them to add the soap extension for you.

You can also force composer to skip the platform requirements check by adding `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch to your `composer install` command. This should force the installation to pass but the library itself might not work properly because of missing extension. You should only do this **when you are sure that the extension is available** but composer cannot see it for some reasons (for example when you are running composer with different php configuration).